# @Requestparam: Can not get the 2nd inputted request parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, curl

I'm trying to create simple REST request handler like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(@RequestParam(name = "test", required = false) String test, 
                   @RequestParam(name ="number", required = false) Long number) {

    return new StringBuilder(test).append(" ").append(number).toString();
}
```

But when I test this by CURL:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/test?test=abc&number=2016
```

The output become like this:

```
abc null
```

What's wrong here? Is this my mistake or Spring bug?
I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.0 (latest version may be).
curl version is 7.43.0 (64 bit).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hopefully this is the solution and not a false assumption:

If you really type:

`curl http://localhost:8080/test?test=abc&number=2016`

Your curl process

`curl http://localhost:8080/test?test=abc`

will be executed and send in the background because of the `&`.

Try:

`curl 'http://localhost:8080/test?test=abc&number=2016'`.

Comment: Thanks you, it work like a charm. P/S: Although i checked it on windows so i used " instead of '

Answer (score 1):

Used curl from cmder on Windows 8.1. Got same issue with multiple Spring @RequestParam annotations. Wrapping url in single quotes did't fix it for me, but double quotes worked as expected.

No quotes approach:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/jobs/test%20name/find?jobTime=jobtime&jobDate=jobdate
```

Will produce *400 Bad request error*, because jobDate parameter marked as mandatory in Spring controller.

Single quotes approach:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/jobs/test%20name/find?jobTime=jobtime&jobDate=jobdate'
```

Will produce *'jobDate' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.* error

Double quotes will behave as expected:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/jobs/test%20name/find?jobDate=jobdate&jobTime=jobtime"
```

Produced correct output from controller class.

Same exact GET request working fine without any quotes if executed via browser address bar.